# Font characters not correct on some devices

Tags: java, android

Why on some devices does my App get badly formatted letters? Mostly, the display is done correctly, but on some devices the replacement of accented letters (ç, á, é ...) is replaced by special characters. How do I solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EjRV.png)

Comment: Please consider adding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are letting the device pick from the fonts it has available and the font it picked doesn't have those characters.  You can [bundle a font with your app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource) or in Android 8.0 and later you can use [downloadable fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts).